# How do i solve this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my piece of code. So taking in and out of my code everywhere, i think i have found the culprit. it is this chunk of code here that is causing it

```
   if (strcmp(input, "load 1") != 0 || strcmp(input, "load 2") != 0 || strcmp(input, "quit") != 0)
    {
        Player player;
        Position position;
        Direction direction;

        char* tok;
        char* firstInput=0;
        char* secondInput=0;
        char* thirdInput=0;
        char* fourthInput=0;
        int x;
        int y;
        char str[10];
        char str2[10];


        tok = strtok(input, " ");
        strcpy(firstInput, tok);            
        tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        strcpy(secondInput, tok);          
        tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        strcpy(thirdInput, tok);          
        tok = strtok(NULL, "");
        strcpy(fourthInput, tok);            

        strcpy(str, secondInput);
        x = atoi(str);
        strcpy(str2, thirdInput);
        y = atoi(str2);

        if(strcmp(firstInput, "init") == 0 )
        {
            if(x >= 0 && x <= 9)
            {
                if(y >= 0 && y <= 9)
                {
                    if (strcmp(fourthInput,"north") == 0 || (strcmp(fourthInput,"south")) || (strcmp(fourthInput,"west") == 0) || (strcmp(fourthInput,"east") == 0))
                    {
                        position.x = x;
                        position.y = y;

                        if(strcmp(fourthInput,"north") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = NORTH;
                        }
                        if(strcmp(fourthInput,"south") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = SOUTH;
                        }
                        if(strcmp(fourthInput,"west") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = WEST;
                        }
                        if(strcmp(fourthInput,"east") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = EAST;
                        }
                        initialisePlayer(&player, &position, direction);
                        placePlayer(board, position);
                        displayDirection(direction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }                      
    }
```

from what i know segmentation fault means a memory problem. I have made sure there is enough space for everything. what is actually going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324796/how-to-debug-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Um, you didn't allocate any memory yet. `firstInput` is still 0.

Comment: Which line does it segfault? What is the backtrace?

Comment: What line does it occur? The debugger can tell us this

Comment: Are you checking if the given input is actually smaller than or equal than the str and str2 buffers?

If not, the problem might be caused by entering more than 12 characters, causing a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `firstInput` and its siblings don't have any memory allocated to the where you could `strcpy` to. They are `NULL`, which leads to a segmentation fault.

You could allocate memory or make these variables local arrays, but you don't really need that. `strtok` returns pointers into `input`. These are valid as long as `input` isn't overwritten. You use these pointers only to analyse the current line before reading the next line into `input`, so that's okay.

Get rid of the intermediary `tok` and store the result of the tokens directly:

```
    char* firstInput = NULL;
    char* secondInput = NULL;

    firstInput = strtok(input, " ");
    if (firstInput) secondInput = strtok(NULL, ", ");

    // analyse input
```

When dealing with pointers, make sure to test for `NULL` before accessing them. There is no guarantee that user input contains exactly four tokens (or any tokens at all).

Answer (score 0):

You could start from here:

```
char* firstInput=0;
...
strcpy(firstInput, tok);
```

where `firstInput` is still NULL, and no memory is allocated for it, but you are trying to copy `tok` to it.

Use [malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to allocate memory, like this:

```
firstInput = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tok) + 1));
if (firstInput==NULL)
  exit (1);
```

This should get you started with your debugging. :)